# How can I limit resources for non root users using CGroups V2 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, cgroup

Currently, I'm limiting the CPU and Memory for different non-root users in my software via Cgroups v1 in Ubuntu 20.04. I want to upgrade my software to Ubuntu 22.04. How can I safely move to that with new resource-limiting approaches in Cgroups v2?